# Copy Row one by one from dataframe to dataframe every 3 seconds

Tags: python, pandas, time, append

I´m trying to transfer rows one by one (from one dataframe, to another) every certain time (for example 3 secs), but I´m stuck with the results.

I share my code by now:

```
import pandas as pd
import time

file_name = 'schio_000_orig.csv'
cor_file = pd.read_csv(file_name,
                    sep=',',
                    header=None,
                    usecols=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
                    names=['COL_1', 'DATE', 'TIME','X', 'N','Y','E','DATA', 'COL_2','COL_3'])


largo = len(cor_file)

base = cor_file.loc[[0]]
    
#appended_data = []

appended_data = cor_file.loc[[0]]

for i in range(largo):
    data = cor_file.loc[[i]]
    appended_data.append(data)
    print(appended_data)
    time.sleep(2)
appended_data = pd.concat(appended_data)
```

Thanks for all.

Comment: Can you share 5 rows or so of sample input data?

Comment: Instead creating new variables and couting the number of rows just run `.iterrows()` on your dataframe. Also plz tell us what are you current results and what do you expect from that code besides having a 1:1 copy of the file you've just imported in the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import time

file_name = 'schio_000_orig.csv'
cor_file = pd.read_csv(file_name,
                sep=',',
                header=None,
                usecols=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
                names=['COL_1', 'DATE', 'TIME','X', 'N','Y','E','DATA', 'COL_2','COL_3'])

appended_data = pd.DataFrame()

for row, cont in cor_file.iterrows():
    appended_data = appended_data.append(cont)
    time.sleep(2)
print(appended_data)
```